# Register Checkbox Condition and Terms

Tags: layout, customer, ce-1.9.1.0, register

Please tell me where I should put anything that I need.
I just want to add checkbox in register to accept conditions and terms (check-box must be checked).

How i can do it?

Answer (score 4):

Add this in register.phtml

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something" name="something" value="1" title="something" class="checkbox required-entry">
```

Comment: First I was like "You can't just put a checkbox in the phtml and expect it to work" but actually with the `required` class you can. Nice one. Although you might want to note that when someone removes the class they can still register without agreeing to the terms.